# Ошибка связанные с log4j при компиляции hadoop программы

Tags: unix, java, log4j, компиляция, linux

Я написал `hadoop` программу с использованием `log4j` и привожу ее часть

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class ParallelIndexation {
    //public static native long Traveser(String Path);

    //public static native void Configure(String Path);

    //static {
    //  System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
    //}
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Map.class.getName());
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
```

В результате компиляции я получил следующие сообщения об ошибках

```
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: <identifier> expected
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
                                 ^
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: illegal start of type
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
                                  ^
2 errors
```

Помогите устранить эти ошибки.

Comment: эти 2 вызова идут вне каких-либо методов поэтому и ругается засуньте их в метод или конструктор класса. если же вы твердо уверены что они лежат в методах то ищите пропущеную скобку (или закаменченную)

Comment: @jmu вы оказались правы. спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария

---

эти 2 вызова идут вне каких-либо методов, поэтому и ругается.

поместите их в метод или конструктор класса.

если же вы твердо уверены, что они находятся внутри методов, то ищите пропущеную скобку (или закомментированную).